# Is there a way to control the tab group order in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, tab-groups

I have lots of tab groups, and I like to use them to store open pages.

I know that you can switch tabs using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>, and that you can open the tab gropus with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to toggle between two tab groups of your choice. If I am working on an old opened tab group, I can't toggle to the newest one with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> even if that was the last group I opened up.

When you right click on a tab, there is the option to 'Move to group' which opens up a list of tab groups. This list is the order that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> will cycle through.

Is there a way of organizing or sorting this list?

Comment: Have you tried the Ctrl+Shift+E

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with ctrl-shift-E, but that does not allow for toggling between groups without using the mouse.

Comment: If you use the tab groups (Ctrl + E) then you can switch between groups using Ctrl + ` and Ctrl + Shift + ` in the same way you would use Ctrl + Tab to switch tabs.

Comment: LOL on my german keyboard, there is no key for just `

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the keystrokes (shortcuts already mentioned by GµårÐïåñ Sep 9 at 21:48) which are necessary to cycle through tab groups, you can rearrange your relevant tab groups side by side:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-organize-tabs#w_how-do-i-organize-my-tab-groups

"Rearranging Tab Groups – Click and drag on an empty area along the sides or bottom of a group to move it around the screen."

Comment: I don't follow that. If you open the tab groups with ctrl-shift-E, and move the groups around, ctrl-` and ctrl-shift-` still seem to maintain the original order. I'm using Firefox 23 in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a key <kbd>`</kbd> on my german keyboard layout, without [changing the keyboard shortcut](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/), I can still use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and then use the **Arrow Keys** to move around all open pages and once I am inside the right area, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>